# Rename a stream in node.js before sending it to client

Tags: javascript, node.js

I have the following code in an expressjs route:

```
readstream.on('error', function (err) {
 console.log('An error occurred!', err);
 throw err;
});

readstream.pipe(res);
```

I want to change the filename because currently it is a random id (it's stored like that in my database).

Comment: It won't be in the stream (streams don't have names), it'll be in the headers. The name is given in the `Content-Disposition` header.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Set a header before sending it --

```
res.header('Content-Disposition', 'attachment; filename="new file name.pdf"');
```